# How to count the number of rows from left join with conditioning

Tags: mysql, postgresql

This is my query:

```
SELECT claims.id,
COUNT(CASE WHEN claims.sold_at BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '7.day') AND now() END FROM claims) week1
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN claims ON claims.sales_user_id = users.id
WHERE users.office_id = 2
```

What I am trying to do is join the claims table but then also get a count of how many were sold_at within a certain date period

This query is giving an error but not sure how to fix/approach it properly?

Comment: Where's your THEN clause in your CASE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
        users.id, count(claims.id) as count
    from users
    left join claims on claims.sales_user_id = users.id
        where
            users.office_id = 2 and
            claims.sold_at between (current_timestamp - interval '7' day) and current_timestamp
        group by users.id;
```

Comment: The condition in the `where` clause turns the `outer` into an `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this

```
SELECT claims.id,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN claims.sold_at BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '7.day') AND now()
               THEN claims.id
               ELSE null END) week1
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN claims ON claims.sales_user_id = users.id
 WHERE users.office_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    users.id,
    count(
        claims.sold_at between (now() - interval '7.day') and now()
        or null
    ) week1
from
    users 
    left join
    claims on claims.sales_user_id = users.id
where users.office_id = 2
group by users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally for this kind of thing you use SUM(IF()).

Something like this:-

```
SELECT claims.id,
    SUM(IF(claims.sold_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND now(), 1, 0)) AS week1
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN claims ON claims.sales_user_id = users.id
WHERE users.office_id = 2
```

But this on its own this makes no sense. Why is claims.id being brought back? The aggregate function without a GROUP BY clause will mean only a single row is returned, so the claims.id returned will be random. But I expect the id is the unique key so grouping by it seems wrong in this case.